# How to run video with mediaelement in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am making a windows phone app,  I want to run the video whenever the button is pressed. I am using **mediaelement** to run it, here is the code:

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" 
                  Margin="0,40,0,40"
                  Height="400" 
                  Width="240" />
<Button x:Name="playVideoButton"
            Height="80"
            Width="200"
            Content="Play Video"
            Click="playVideoButton_Click"/>
```

C#:

```
private void playVideoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Video.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   myMediaElement.Play();
 }
```

this is the basic code that i am trying to run the video so if this one runs i'll add pause feature as well, but unfortunately its not running.
Please help and thanks in Advance!
Shahrukh

Answer (score 0):

you can refer a **Nokia Developer** Sample about [Video Playback with MediaElement in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone) `or` you can Use **Media Player launcher** instead. here is a **MSDN Documentation** about it. [How to use the Media Player launcher for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394004(v=vs.105).aspx)